# What's the difference between "./<executable>" and ". ./<executable>"?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

For the most part, many bash commands work the same either way but some don't. I'm confused on what exactly the difference is. To clarify, it's the difference between:

```
./file.sh
```

and

```
. ./file.sh
```

Comment: The first one executes a file. The latter sources a file. The difference is that the latter affects your current environment. The former executes in a sub-shell. The latter executes in the current shell.

Comment: `help .` and `help source` should give you the same info/output.

Comment: Not all executables can be sourced like a script without causing issues, but all of them can be executed as a file provided the proper permissions and "deep" internal setup to identify and run executables based on their magic value.